Overwrite email address and mobile number for selected contacts without deleting them
We have a requirement to implement a masking mechanism (overwriting existing values) of both email addresses and mobile numbers values for specific contacts within all MC attribute groups configured in the BU. We are aware of the contact deletion option but as you can see this does more than necessary in this use case. We tried to utilize the Update Contact REST API call but since mobile number cannot be updated in Mobile Demographics using this call - this cannot be a valid solution.
Any other suggestion (besides contact deletion)?
Thanks,
Barak
